# Diffraction using a phone

Tags: diffraction, home-experiment

[image]

I used my phone to create a diffraction pattern and measure the number of pixels along the horizontal. I used the formula in the picture and calculated everything using readings ive added in the picture. however, I got an answer around 173 times the actual. however, when I changed the formula to minus instead of plus, I got a pretty accurate answer. Is the formula I'm using wrong? I did find 1 source with this 'minus' in the formula and 2 sources with 'plus'... what else could have gone wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate on your method of measurement as well as the formula used.

Comment: What formula are you talking about? What sources did you use? And how did you use your phone to create a diffraction pattern? Please elaborate.

Comment: i hope the picture makes it clear...

Comment: Can you provide more details, like the numbers you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ray diagram for a reflection grating looks something like this with $AB$ and $A’B’$ as the incident parallel waves and $BC$ and $B’C’$ as the reflected rays.

[image].

If you look at the path differences $d \sin \theta$ and $d \sin \phi$ you should see that they occur along different rays and so the net path difference is found by subtracting the path differences.

A Huygens wavelets interpretation of the spectrum produced by a reflection grating is [shown in this answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328250/104696)

Comment: hi I'm so sorry I'm just worried about using the wrong formula in my report, so i had another question. the difference is found by subtracting but some websites say that the angle of diffraction is on the other side of the normal, hence its negative. so the formula becomes sin theta - (-sin phi) = sin theta + sin phi...

Comment: @Vanessa That is perfectly acceptable and then you are using the relationship for rays which ate “below” the red rays in my diagram.

Comment: just to clarify - i use minus?

Comment: @Vanessa Do not just think “formulae”. Redraw the diagram with the green rays “below” the red rays and see what happen to the path difference.