# Does a diffraction grating not follow the law of reflection?

Tags: optics, reflection

The Law of Reflection states that the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence.

However, consider the case of a diffraction grating with light incident at only one specific direction, how come the reflected light comes off as at range of different angles?[image]

Comment: The elementary laws of reflection (Hero of Alexandria) and of refraction (Snellius) ignore *diffraction*, they are true only when the reflecting/refracting surfaces are smooth over scales of many wavelengths; an optical grating enhances diffraction. Toraldo di Francia generalized the laws of Hero and Snellius in his so-called para-geometrical optics to take account diffraction effects in reflection and refraction but these ideas were soon generalized and replaced by Keller's more general Geometrical Theory of Diffraction and is widely used in modern simulation packages of EM scattering.

Comment: @hyportnex I thought diffraction are applicable when light passes through an aperture.  Are there diffraction of light reflecting off a finite mirror?

Comment: the diffraction (and of course interference, too) occurs here at the edges of the grooves or bevels (those sharp edges that break the smoothness of the surface) of the grating.

Comment: Diffraction is in the nature of wave propagation and manifests itself whenever the propagating wave encounters an obstacle, any obstacle, not just a hole in a screen. Always remember Huygens' principle when thinking of propagation and you will not be misled...

Comment: @hyportnex Ahh I understand now, my professor never explained to me from this perspective.  May I ask how did you know that? Are you a researcher in this area?

Comment: naah, just been around and seen a lot...

Comment: [Related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328250/104696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, diffraction from a reflective grating produces multiple diffraction orders: 0, -1, +1, -2, +2, and so on.  The 0th order *is* the ordinary reflection.  The other orders are offset from the 0th order according to the grating equation.  The detailed shape of the grooves in the grating affects how much light goes into each order.  This is explained [here](https://www.newport.com/t/grating-physics).

Comment: My point is shouldn't all the light go in the direction of the 0th order, since the law of reflection tells us that the angle of reflection is always equal to the angle of incidence?

Comment: The 0th diffraction order is *not* the same as the classical reflected ray. The former spreads out as a fan and its spreading angle is roughly the distance between the edges divided by the wavelength. The "classical" ray does not spread.

Comment: @hyporonex, Please provide a reference; or at least an explanation to your assertion that the 0th order spreads out in a fan.  It certainly does not conform to my experience in the lab.

Comment: @S.McGrew Can you explain to me why are there diffraction in this case? I thought it is applicable only when light passes through a hole/obstacle.

Comment: Just think of how the reflected orders are formed: the incident plane wave is reflected from several *finite* pieces of glass, from one edge of the tilted piece until the next tilted piece without direct contribution from the sides, so it is restricted in extent over the tilt, hence it must show diffraction. You cannot constrain a plane wave without spreading; if the constrain is much wider than the wavelength it is more difficult observe the spread but it is there.

Comment: say, each little tilted mirror has width $d$ then one reflection will have roughly $d/\lambda$ spread in radians, if you now coherently combine the reflections from N tilts then the spread is narrower by that factor to be $\approx d/(N\lambda)$. If $N$ is large as it is usually in practice the spread can be very small but it is there.

Comment: @hyportnex of course the reflection at a mirror is a convolution of a plane wave with the fourier transformation of the finite shape of the mirror/grating. In many cases, for example during shaving on front of a mirror, this is a negligible effect. In such cases the mirror/grating can  be considered infinite and the answer is correct.

Comment: @my2cts it may be "of course" to you but not necessarily to everybody. Anyhow the issue is not whether the effect is negligible under certain circumstances but rather the effect exists and if yes why; that is all.

Comment: @hyportnex Should we then also take into account gravity ? Our mirrors are slightly bent. Also there will be diffuse scattering due to roughness, Goos-Hänchen effects, absorption, recoil, deformation, acoustic noise, electronic shot noise, thermal emission. I am sure the list goes on. Any law, also Snell's, has limited validity.